# How to access IHostingEnvironment in middleware class

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

In Asp.Net Core if a custom piece of middleware is created and placed in it's own class how does one get access to `IHostingEnvironment` from inside the middleware?

For example in my class below I thought I could inject `IHostingEnvironment` into the contstructor but it's always null.  Any other ideas on how to get access to `IHostingEnvironment`?

```
public class ForceHttps {
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _env;

    /// <summary>
    /// This approach to getting access to IHostingEnvironment 
    /// doesn't work.  It's always null
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="next"></param>
    /// <param name="env"></param>
    public ForceHttps(RequestDelegate next, IHostingEnvironment env) {
        _next = next;
    }


    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context) {
        string sslPort = "";
        HttpRequest request = context.Request;


        if(_env.IsDevelopment()) {
            sslPort = ":44376";
        }

        if(request.IsHttps == false) {
            context.Response.Redirect("https://" + request.Host + sslPort + request.Path);
        }

        await _next.Invoke(context);

    }
}
```

Comment: My bad,  injecting into the constructor does work, I just forgot to assign the constructor parameter to the member var _env.  So later in the Invoke method, _env is null.  Hand against forehead!  It's great to learn that I can inject it into the Invoke method though.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

method injection works, just add it to the method signature

```
 public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, IHostingEnvironment env) {...}
```

Answer (score 2):

Now days, on modern .NET version, the solution might look like:

```
public CustomMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IWebHostEnvironment env) {...}
```

The new `IWebHostEnvironment` have to be passed into middleware constructor instead of deprecated `IHostingEnvironment`.